# Removing the settings menu inflator from Actionbar

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a action bar set up as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExJSk.jpg):

When I click on it a settings popup appears like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdeyS.jpg) which when pressed takes me to my apps settings page.

My question is how would I remove the settings popup so that it takes me directly to my settings activity when I press the three dotted button? I tried playing around with code below but it yielded no result.

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto the menu folder of your project. res>>menu and find the xml file representing the

You have to add the `android:showAsAction="always"` like below:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:id="@+id/menu"
       android:title="@string/menu_settings_item"
       android:showAsAction="always"
       android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_a" />
 </menu>
```

Comment: ic_menu_a does not seem to exist for me.

Comment: add your Icon that you want to show up in the drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that your settings option always appears as a button on the action bar. You don't need the three dots in this case.

For instance, you can specify your action bar menu item like this (notice the "**always**" value):

```
   <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="always" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the showAsAction parameter.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:id="@+id/menu"
       android:title="@string/menu_settings_item"
       android:showAsAction="always"
       android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_a" />
 </menu>
```